# undefined error on defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's a simple check and ajax send  function

`fcell` is the cell number and `v_cell` is the first 3 digits which should be in the 091-3 range .

so i get them both and when i alert them everything is ok (i get 3 alert for each one though )but as it sends the ajax request i get this error

```
TypeError: fcell is undefined
[Break On This Error]   
var v_cell = fcell.slice(0,3);
```

here is the code

```
var finprog = false;    
    $('.send_to_friend').click(function(){

    var tr     = $(this).parent().parent();
    var p      = $(this).parent();
    var fcell  = tr.find('.fcell').val();
    var fname  = tr.find('.fname').val();
    var funame = tr.find('.funame').val();
    var v_cell = fcell.slice(0,3);
    alert(fcell);
    alert(v_cell);


    if(isNaN(fcell))
    { 
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }

    if(fcell.length != 11 )
    { 
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }

    if(v_cell != 091 && v_cell != 092 && v_cell != 093 )
    { 
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }


    if(fname.length == 0 )
    {
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }


    if(funame.length == 0 )
    {
        alert('error');
        return false;
    }

    if(finprog) return false;
    finprog = true ;

    var id  = tr.attr('class');
    p.html('<img src="images/load_square.gif" width="27" height="27" />');

    $.post('aj.php' , { name:fname , uname:funame , cell:fcell , sms_id:id , doo : 'sent_to_friend' }
     , function(data) { 
     finprog = false;

        if($.trim(data) == 'ok')
        {
            p.html('ok');
        }
        else
        {
            p.html('error');
        }
    })


})
```

it doesn't make any sense

here is my ajax parameters . it's defined here ! `cell    09163105802`

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
cell    09125105802
doo sent_to_friend
name    x
sms_id  9
uname   x
```

Comment: what is `tr.find('.fcell').length` ?

Comment: `parent().parent()` is very error-prone, too tied to a very specific HTML structure, you should use `tr = parent("tr")` which still works if you add a wrapping div around your content

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely receiving this error because your tr object is null. Therefore, when you try to find the element with the class fcell it returns null as well.

```
var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
// tr is most likely null here
var fcell  = tr.find('.fcell').val();
// therefore fcell cannot be found and is undefined
```

If this is the case, I recommend that you use the following to find your tr.

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
```

Comment: @max Sounds like it's the problem, you should debug your code and find the value of fcell just right after you assign it a value.

Comment: thanx but as i said when i alert the fcell i get the right number so i don't think this is the issue here .

Comment: @JuanMendes thanx as you can see right after defining fcell and v_cell i've put alerts and they return the right number

Comment: @max I don't see how you are receiving that error if fcell actually has content. Can you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that receives the same error so that we can test some for ourselves.